# Does anyone know of a PaaS provider that supports .NET and can open TCP and UDP sockets via system.net and/or unmanaged dll?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, websocket, paas

As the question suggests, Ive searched several providers to no avail. That all seem to support ASP.NET only. Even IronFoundry only supports ASP.NET?

Comment: It appears that [stackato](http://www.activestate.com/stackato) supports .NET apps and has an addon called [harbor](http://docs.stackato.com/deploy/services/port-service.html) that adds tcp sockets. It looks like it isn't hosted though